# copy of pointer report different value

Tags: c, pointers

i am building game's item system using c.

I want to use a header to store the address of item array that,
when this program run, header will return the address of the
corresponding address.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct Header{
struct ItmInfo *itmAddress;
// a pointer that store the address of ItmInfo array
...//some variables
}Head;

struct ItmInfo{
...    //some variables
}Itm;  //struct for Item

int main()
{
    struct Header *head=malloc(1*sizeof (*head)); //open a header array, currently it have only 1 member 
    struct ItmInfo *itm= malloc (memStack*sizeof(*itm));// open a item array
 
    head[0].itmAddress = itm; //copy item array address in to the header

    printf ("Address of item list is %p\n",*itm);
    printf ("Address in header is %p\n",head[0].itmAddress);

    return 0;
}
```

This code can run, however, those address are not in same value

The result:

```
Address of item list is 000000000061fd20
Address in header is    0000000000081490
```

What have i done wrong, is it ok to do so at the first place??, Thank you

Comment: `*itm` and `itm` are not the same thing, so of course it prints different values.

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf ("Address of item list is %p\n",*itm);
```

should be

```
printf ("Address of item list is %p\n", (void *)itm);
```

Comment: More properly, it should be `printf("Address of item list is %p.\n", (void *) itm);`. Pointers should be cast to `void *` for printing with `%p`. It is unusual these days for different types of pointers to have different representations, but the C standard allows it and says the argument for `%p` should have type `void *`. Also, I inserted a period because sentences should end with a period (or question mark or exclamation mark).

Comment: @EricPostpischil,  I'm surprised that (*itm) prints anything at all. At least in VS I get a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You dereference the pointer and push to the stack the whole structure (it can be megabytes of data like in this example 80.000.000 bytes of data :) https://godbolt.org/z/qYMM67). It is Undefined Behaviour.

you want to display the reference stored in itm pointer.

```
    printf ("Address of item list is %p\n", (void *)itm);
    printf ("Address in header is %p\n", (void *)head[0].itmAddress);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8sdvhT

If you the cast to `void *` the line `printf ("Address of item list is %p\n",(void *)*itm);` would never compile